# How to sort artifacts based on 'Last pushed' in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am trying to figure out how to sort artifacts in Azure DevOps. Is there a way I can view recently pushed artefact for a particular feed instead of trying to filter based on package names?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but for now we don't support sort based on `Last Pushed date`. Azure Devops sorts the packages based on `PackageName` by default.

I'm afraid you have to use Filter and Feed button to find your package:

[image]

I think your idea is meaningful, so I add a feature request for you in User Voice Forum. You can vote for it and track the issue there, the product team would consider about it if it gets enough points.

Link here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1089652/support-sorting-packages-in-azure-artifact-feed-vi.html